# Remove blank (empty) space from PDF template after flattenning an empty AcroField using iTextSharp, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I am filling a `PDF` template that contains `AcroFields` using `iTextSharp` via `Windows Forms` application. 
The data is filled via interface with multiple `comboBoxes` as the following:

```
string template = path1 + @"\Template1.pdf";
PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(template);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item> de in
pdfreader.AcroFields.Fields)
    {
       sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }

string newPDF = path + @"\"name".pdf";
PdfStamper pdfstamper = new PdfStamper(pdfreader, new FileStream(newPDF,
FileMode.Create));
AcroFields pdffields = pdfstamper.AcroFields;
pdffields.SetField("ProductText", product.SelectedItem.ToString());
pdffields.SetField("indexText", index.SelectedItem.ToString());
 .
 .
 .

pdfstamper.FormFlattening = true;
pdfstamper.Close();
```

The result in the `PDF` is as the following image:

[image: result in PDF]

But the question is: When the `Grade` is not selected (as shown in the previous image), I can remove the whole row of the `Grade`, but this will leave a blank empty space in the `PDF` as shown in the following image:

[image: PDF with blank space of empty flattened field]

What are the possible ways to remove the empty blank space of the flattened empty fields? is it by shifting up the content that follows the space? Thanks.

Comment: shrink the column before you pass to pdf

Comment: @JojiThomasEapen, I didn't get your point. The template already has the AcroFields in it. I am only passing the values selected from `comboBoxes` to those AcroFields.

Comment: @TempoClick AcroForm forms are meant to represent static layouts at fixed positions, so removing something won't shift anything else. Yes, you can try and shift up the AcroForm fields beneath the empty field but most likely the labels at their left are not form field or some other annotations; I assume them to be regular page content. Shifting up page content is more difficult.

Comment: Thank you @mkl. I can handle the labels issue, but how can I shift the fields below? I need to know this. thanks

Comment: @TempoClick Does my answer show you how to shift the fields below?

Comment: @mkl Can I specify the fields to be shifted rather than shifting all below fields?

Comment: @TempoClick Well, somehow that should be possible. But how should they be shifted? By a constant offset as in the answer? Or should each of the fields on the given list be shifted to the position of the previous one on the list? Or the nearest position above from the positions of the listed fields?

Comment: @mkl Let's say I want only **Customer1** to be shifted to the position of **SomeGrade**.

Comment: @TempoClick Cf. the edit of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The OP indicated in a comment to the question*

> *I can handle the labels issue, but how can I shift the fields below?*

*Thus, the following code deals only with the fields.*

#### Move up all fields below the empty field

So let's assume you check the value you have for a field before setting the field to it. If in case of an empty value you do not set the field value but instead call a method like the following to move up every field below that field:

```
void MoveUp(PdfStamper stamper, String fieldName, int pageNumber)
{
    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
    IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions = fields.GetFieldPositions(fieldName);
    foreach (AcroFields.FieldPosition position in positions)
    {
        if (position.page == pageNumber)
        {
            IList<float> fieldYsBelowField = new List<float>();
            PdfDictionary pageDict = stamper.Reader.GetPageN(pageNumber);
            PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            for (int i = 0; i < annots.Size; i++)
            {
                PdfDictionary annot = annots.GetAsDict(i);
                PdfArray rect = annot.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
                if (((PdfNumber)rect[1]).FloatValue < position.position.Bottom)
                {
                    fieldYsBelowField.Add(((PdfNumber)rect[1]).FloatValue);
                }
            }
            if (fieldYsBelowField.Count > 0)
            {
                float offset = position.position.Bottom - fieldYsBelowField.Max();
                for (int i = 0; i < annots.Size; i++)
                {
                    PdfDictionary annot = annots.GetAsDict(i);
                    PdfArray rect = annot.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
                    if (((PdfNumber)rect[1]).FloatValue < position.position.Bottom)
                    {
                        rect[1] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[1]).FloatValue + offset);
                        rect[3] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[3]).FloatValue + offset);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you'll get what you want.

E.g. if for some single page form the following code

```
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("Product", "Product1");
fields.SetField("Index", "XQAA-0000-000");
fields.SetField("Quality", "USP,");
fields.SetField("Grade", "SomeGrade");
fields.SetField("Customer", "Customer1");
fields.SetField("Market", "England, Germany");
```

results in

[image: Screenshot all filled]

and

```
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("Product", "Product1");
fields.SetField("Index", "XQAA-0000-000");
fields.SetField("Quality", "USP,");
fields.SetField("Customer", "Customer1");
fields.SetField("Market", "England, Germany");
```

results in

[image: Screenshot with empty grade]

then

```
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("Product", "Product1");
fields.SetField("Index", "XQAA-0000-000");
fields.SetField("Quality", "USP,");
MoveUp(stamper, "Grade", 1);
fields.SetField("Customer", "Customer1");
fields.SetField("Market", "England, Germany");
```

results in

[image: Screenshot with empty grade and fields below moved up]

#### Move up only one field

In comments to the question the OP asked

> Can I specify the fields to be shifted rather than shifting all below fields? [...] Let's say I want only Customer1 to be shifted to the position of SomeGrade.

A helper routine for this is even simpler:

```
void MoveUp(PdfStamper stamper, String fieldName, String moveFieldName, int pageNumber)
{
    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
    IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions = fields.GetFieldPositions(fieldName);
    foreach (AcroFields.FieldPosition position in positions)
    {
        if (position.page == pageNumber)
        {
            Item moveFieldItem = fields.GetFieldItem(moveFieldName);
            for (int i = 0; i < moveFieldItem.Size; i++)
            {
                if (moveFieldItem.GetPage(i) == pageNumber)
                {
                    PdfDictionary annot = moveFieldItem.GetWidget(i);
                    PdfArray rect = annot.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
                    float offset = position.position.Bottom - ((PdfNumber)rect[1]).FloatValue;
                    rect[1] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[1]).FloatValue + offset);
                    rect[3] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[3]).FloatValue + offset);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method,

```
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("Product", "Product1");
fields.SetField("Index", "XQAA-0000-000");
fields.SetField("Quality", "USP,");
MoveUp(stamper, "Grade", "Customer", 1);
fields.SetField("Customer", "Customer1");
fields.SetField("Market", "England, Germany");
```

results in

[image: Screenshot with empty grade and field "Customer" moved up]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. One thing more; In case of shifting Right or Left, only `position.Bottom` should be changed?

Comment: @TempoClick *"In case of shifting Right or Left, only position.Bottom should be changed?"* - I don't understand your question; if you wanted to shift a field to the left or the right, you would *not* change `position.Bottom` (unless the page rotation is 90° or 270°, that is).

Comment: That's what I meant. If it is not the `position.Bottom`, what would be the routine to shift a field left to the position of the previous field?

Comment: As you see in the code, I change the values of `rect[1]` and `rect[3]` is are the bottom and top y coordinates. If you want to move a field to the right or the left, change the values of `rect[0]` and `rect[2]`, the left and right x coordinates of the field.